# Inserting new field with first three characters from the shapefile name using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator

Is there any Python script which will add a field to shapefile which will be corresponding to first three characters from the shapefile name?

Answer (score 3):

you can do this with Add Field (Data Management).

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "C:/test.gdb"

inFeat = "cityoflondon.shp"
fieldLength = 10

#it will return "cit" from inFeat
fieldName = str(inFeat[:3])

arcpy.AddField_management(inFeat, fieldName, "TEXT", "", "", fieldLength)
```

Comment: I forgot to add that i need to add field in multiple shapefiles at once. I have one hundred shapefiles. Sorry, my mistake!

Answer (score 3):

This code should do the trick.  New field should be titled "New"

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"c:\Temp"
shapename = "newshape.shp"
newfield = shapename[0:3]
arcpy.AddField_management(shapename,newfield,"TEXT","","","20")
```

Comment: `shapename[0:3]` would give the first 4 letters, no?

Comment: @Roy, This notation starts at and includes the first number, and ends at, but excludes, the last number.

Comment: Thanks, indexing always gets me.  Thank god for trial and error.